# Search Specific File In Subdirectories In Directory Polling

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a beginner in Python and already seeking for the answer for some time, but none can solve.

Currently I'm doing script to scan directory & subdirectories changes in a path using directory polling. And if the new changes in the directory occurs (in this case it will be folders), it should be able to scan deep in the subdirectories and scanning for the specific extension files inside (in this case .txt file). This code doesn't work, it think the problem started when the script want to scan added folder, and goes in the folder to search .txt files.

```
import os, time
import glob

path_to_watch="C:\Temp"
before=dict ([(f,None) for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch)])

x=1
while x==1:
    time.sleep(5) #snooze time for each loop iteration
    after = dict ([(f,None) for f in os.listdir(path_to_watch)])
    added = [f for f in after if not f in before]

    if added:
        for path, dirs, files in os.walk(added):
        new_dir=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(added))
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(new_dir):
            for name in files:
                if name.endswith((".txt")):
                    print "Clear"
    before=after
```